# web-app_2_5.xsd showing errors when validating web.xml in eclipse

Tags: java, xml, jakarta-ee

I have no idea what I could've done to cause this because my time spent programming is stretched out and I've already forgotten what I might've done. But now when I load Eclipse it says:

```
The errors below were detected when validating the file "web-app_2_5.xsd" via the file "web.xml".  In most cases these errors can be detected by validating "web-app_2_5.xsd" directly.  However it is possible that errors will only occur when web-app_2_5.xsd is validated in the context of web.xml. 
s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements other than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'JDK 6 XML-related APIs'.
The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.
```

My first few lines of web.xml looks like so.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
 id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
```

I've read that it could be an error with the server where the file is being retrieved from, or with caching. I've disabled and cleared the cache and as far as I can tell the server is the same everyone else is using unless they switched to an oracle.com url and I haven't found it yet.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Kev: Perhaps I'm missing something, but what does this question have to do with geography?

Comment: @MichaelScheper - read the full close reason and the accepted answer - "a specific moment in time". This was a problem specific to a very short moment in time when Oracle broke something temporarily with the servers that host various XML schemas that Eclipse relies on.

Comment: @Kev: Fair enough. I had the same issue yesterday, however, and I found this post helpful. It suggested network connectivity issue, which turned out to be correct, despite the error implying a formatting issue.

Comment: @Kev The Q&A here helped me today.

Comment: This question and one of the answers just solved my problem.

Comment: The problem's still occurring with other former Sun Microsystems schema urls, e.g. http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd

Comment: We should all vote for **"reopen"** since this problem still occurs for http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_5.xsd namespace locations!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/f9sxu . The problem is Oracle, again.
I cannot deploy on SGES 2.1.1 with the connection to the internet. When I turned it off, deploy was slow, but successful. It seems the validator tries to refresh cached schemas and to download them from the schemaLocation URLs.

```
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd
GET /xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd ... 
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently to Location: 
  http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/xml/index.html
```

But there is no such schema!

I will try to find some good solution, but the best is maybe to punch up someone in Oracle ...

EDIT: It is fixed at this time (27.1.2010, 20:00 CET), Oracle returns the schema - you can check it with wget. Browsers are redirected to docs. Nice :-)

Comment: Oracle seems to have removed the file again (ten years later). Try using this one: http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd

Answer (score 23):

Andrew, I'm afraid that your namespace is not correct. I think that version 2.5 should be under javaee namespace (JDK, Java 1.5 and 1.6), not j2ee (J2SDK, Java 1.4).

So replace

```
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_5.xsd
```

with

```
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd
```

Comment: http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd is dead??? what is next domain???

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at your web.xml

Are there any ´&´-signs, which are *not* followed by an known XML-Entity? `&uuml;` are HTML-Entities, *not* XML-Entites.

Answer (score 1):

or write own entity resolver that will lookup those entities locally

in case, for example, hibernate, it is enough to point schema location in proper way:
excerpt of hibernate's `DTDEntityResolver`

```
private static final String USER_NAMESPACE = "classpath://";
 ...
public InputSource resolveEntity(String publicId, String systemId) {
 ...
else if ( systemId.startsWith( USER_NAMESPACE ) ) {
...
```

in case of eclipse, you can point to local xsd in: Preferences-->XML-->XML Catalog.